# How to map signalr user to connection (Web Api)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, signalr

Previously I used `Context.User.Identity.Name` to map connection,
but when I moved Hubs to Web Api it stopped working 
(SignalR client and all Identity logic is in asp.net mvc app).
Any ideas?